# SQL Mirroring on Live System?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, mirroring

My project has a SQL 2008 database with production data on it in use at all times.  We need to move our entire production network from one hosting environment to another.  We've already stood up the other hosting environment and it is on a new domain with an install of SQL 2008 that we want to move the database to.

I'm looking for simple to follow instructions on how to set up database mirroring so the data also goes to this other database so we can flip a switch and transition to the new database without causing any downtime in production.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better served with replication instead of mirroring. 
[High availability options](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2482/sql-server-high-availability-options/)

That being said, there are a lot of good guides out there for setting up transactional replication, which is probably what you want to look into. [SQL-Performance guide.](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/transactional-replication-2008-r2/)

Just as a quick note, SQL server 2008 mainstream support has ended, you might want to consider upgrading. [support cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms803962.aspx)

Comment: Alas, upgrading costs money my project does not have.  Thank you for the resources you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of Software options like [Attunity's Replicate](http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-replicate/) and [dbForge's Compare](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/) the latter has a 30 day trial you could use for your switch.

If you just want to sync the tables before switching checkout [this resource](http://jackofalltradesdeveloper.blogspot.mx/2012/03/copy-tables-from-sql-server-to-sql.html). It uses the Management Studio to perform a Sync, it's easy and should work. I used it to sync a local DB to AzureSQL successfully. Just disregard the parts that add SQL for Azure.

For an automated way to do it with SSIS checkout:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorgepc/archive/2010/12/07/synchronize-two-tables-using-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-part-i-of-ii.aspx. Might be what you want.